# HDInsight cluster - attach storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to attach extra blob container to running HDInsight cluster? I did not find any solution.

I need to attach existing blob container using SAS (shared access signatures).

Edit:

Thanks for Shradha R answer - By editing Hadoop core-site.xml you can also attach storage accounts from different data-center, which is impossible during wizard creation.
Attached storage is accessible immediately for Pig scripts (without restart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so straight forward solution is to edit core-site.xml and add the extra storage. You will need to restart head and data nodes.

See if this helps :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cindygross/archive/2013/04/25/access-azure-blob-stores-from-hdinsight.aspx